# `Box` and `&` behave differently with regard to lifetimes?

Tags: rust

When I want to return a closure from a function, I need to use a trait object. Because this is dynamically sized, we of course need some indirection. A very easy example is

```rust
fn returns_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    Box::new(|x| x + 1)
}
```

and indeed, it works just as expected. However, when I replace the `Box` by a normal reference, i.e.

```rust
fn returns_closure() -> &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    &(|x| x + 1)
}
```

I get the error

```
  --> src/main.rs:70:25
   |
70 | fn returns_closure() -> &dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 {
   |                         ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
   |
70 | fn returns_closure() -> &'static dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 {
   |                          +++++++
```

Why is this? Why do I need a lifetime annotation here at all?

One explanation would be that `&` just references the closure `(|x| x+1)` directly, which is (without further annotation) dropped immediately at the end of the function, whereas the `Box`type actually creates a copy of this closure on the heap.

Am I correct in this understanding?

Comment: Also your first sentence is wrong. You can return closures with `impl Trait` syntax: `-> impl Fn(i32) -> i32`

Comment: Indeed the pointed question provides an answer: you cannot return a reference to a temporary object without an explicit lifetime. But to be more specific : in this case `Box` does not "create a copy", it takes ownership of the closure. This is because it does not contain a reference to it, it *holds* it completely. And since you return the Box and not a reference to it (which you couldn't either), the caller of the function receives the ownership of it. So in the end, the caller will *own* a `Box` that owns the closure.

Comment: Also note that you could write `fn returns_closure<'a>() -> &'a dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 { &(|x| x + 1) }`, but in this case the lifetime `'a` would be implicitly be `'static`, which means it would live "forever" (which may not be what you want).

Comment: @fruphon Thanks, makes a lot more sense knowing that `'a` would be `'static` anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need the lifetime annotation or not depends on the function signature. Without looking at the implementation of the function, the compiler (and readers of the documentation) will try to infer its lifetime. The [rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) is as follows:

> If there is exactly one lifetime used in the parameters (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

In this case there are zero lifetimes used in the parameters (because there are zero parameters), so no lifetime is inferred and you will have to explicitly specify the lifetime of the return value. In this case, as the compilation message suggests, you'll want to use a static lifetime (especially since this is a closure that does not capture any variables). You can do this by writing `&'static` instead of `&` in the function signature. This is a type of reference that gives the caller the most flexibility.

> Why is this? Why do I need a lifetime annotation here at all?

Even though the lifetime could be inferred in this case, this rule has the advantage that it is more clear when reading the code that this function returns a static lifetime. Just like it can often be inferred what the return type is, explicitly specifying it provides additional documentation and a sanity check that your code is returning the right type.

I do think that Rust's error message is more cryptic than necessary. The return type contains a borrowed value? It would be more accurate to say that the return type is the type of a borrowed value. Or as it is usually called: a reference. The message could just say: the return type is a reference with an implicit lifetime but there is no parameter to copy the lifetime from.

> whereas the Boxtype actually creates a copy of this closure on the heap. Am I correct in this understanding?

The key difference with the `Box` is that the contents of the `Box` are copied onto the heap and will be deallocated whenever the `Box` is deallocated. The caller will thus take ownership of the box and by proxy of the associated data on the heap. In a static reference scenario, the closure is stored statically in the program and a reference to this data is returned by the function.